# (Internal error) /sbin/upstart

Tags: boot, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu on a quick computer I slapped together. The installation took about 3 hours, after that booting up takes 20 minutes... When I opened Ubuntu I was welcomed to an error

```
The application upstart has experienced an internal error.

ExecutablePath
/sbin/upstart
```

I know this isn't a hard drive failure because this drive has loaded Windows 7 (before I erased it) quick and simply, but what is going on? How do I fix this error?

I'm also experiencing crashes in applications.

The system specs aren't the best:

- Cpu: Athlon 64 x2 dual core (@2.16GHZ)
- Ram: 4GB DDR2
- Gpu: sapphire HD 6570
- OS type: 64bit
- Storage: 500GB

I've use Ubuntu on quite a few computers within my house, but I have never encountered this error before.

Comment: 16.04 should not use `upstart` at all by default but `systemd` instead, I thought... Strange.

Comment: Yeah you're right. If you have installed upstart-sysv it uses upstart and does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this, but only in 16.04 (not 14.04). I fixed it by booting with systemd by going into `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` in the GRUB menu and selecting `my-kernel-version (systemd)`. Then once I booted I made systemd the default boot:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd-sysv
```

Comment: How would I find this option?

Comment: I tired going into advanced settings > grub and all it did was do some stuff and prompt me to continue... Never saw an option